# How to use CollapsiblePanel

Tags: asp.net

work on C# asp.net vs05 .I want to use CollapsiblePanel on my asp.net project.I can use it on AJAX project. How to use it with out AJAX.Give me syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery's toggle() function
It has overloads which allow you to control the speed of expansion and collapsing